# How detect a buffer overflow with splint

Tags: c, overflow, splint

I'm trying to use splint to detect some bug in  my code. One of more critical point is the buffer overflow detection and seem that splint is not able to do that.
I've tried with a simple C-code

```
void test()
 {
    int i;
    int a[10]
    for(i=0;i<12;i++)
        a[i]=i;
 }
```

This code generate a core dump but the Splint log is empty
I runned splint with default flag
Any suggestion about to detect this ?
Thanks

Comment: Even gcc with default settings manages to find the bug. I would consider the possibility of Splint being useless crap. See this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235204/odd-behavior-from-splint-bounds-checking

Comment: Own experience: Splint's bound checking is far from being usable.

Answer (score 0):

+bounds option solve my problem:
Possible out-of-bounds store: a[i]
Unable to resolve constraint:
requires i @ test.c:6:11 <= 9
needed to satisfy precondition:
requires maxSet(a @ test.c:6:9) >= i @ test.c:6:11
A memory write may write to an address beyond the allocated buffer. (Use
-boundswrite to inhibit warning)

additional info :
splint +bounds  to run the check
I found the flag looking into all flag availbale in splint and get more detail in specific help:

splint --help flags alpha
splint --help bounds

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).